# AS3 Replay all the child timelines?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Flash CS5 AS3
Is there a way to reset all the timelines while/if the Frame 1 en Scene 1 is called?

I happen to have lots symbols with timelines, if I gotoAndPlay Scene 1 frame 1, most symbols  won't restart.

I use

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay("one");
```

Comment: What's with the `"one"`? Are you using timeline markers? If you want to go to frame one, then you should call `gotoAndPlay(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one level of children, it's easy. You just loop through them and call `gotoAndPlay` like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i< MovieClip(root).numChildren; i++) 
{
    MovieClip(root).getChildAt(i).gotoAndPlay("one");
}
```

But if you have multiple levels of children, you should do a recursion through all children and run the code above for all of them.